# UIImageView size in UITableViewCell not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to create a rounded image in my UITableViewCell, I have set the image height and width constraints to 80, and when i try to do:

```
cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.frame.size.width/2
cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

My image is diamond shaped instead of a circle. I've checked the width and height for the image and instead of 80 it shows: 128 and 240. 
I also want to add that if I use a constant value of cornerRadius to 40 it works perfectly. 
Could someone explain to me why does it work one way and the frame.size method gives me a false result? Is there any way to get a circle image without having to use a constant value?

That's how I set the UIImageView size:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cXXI.png

EDIT:

I have a custom TableViewCell class

```
class ContactTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nicknameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var avatarImage: UIImageView!
```

}

And in TableViewController I call *cellForRowAtIndexPath*

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ContactTableViewCell

    cell.nicknameLabel.text = "Nick"
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = "Desc"
    cell.avatarImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    cell.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.avatarImage.frame.size.width/2
    cell.avatarImage.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
}
```

and when I try to call

```
print(cell.avatarImage.frame.size.width)
```

it returns value of 240.0

That's what I get when i take the frame.size value instead of setting a constant value
https://i.stack.imgur.com/22t71.png

Comment: please elaborate properly and share some more code abt how to assigned the image width and height?

Comment: Have you checked UIImageView sizes or your just uiimage? What content mode do you use in UIImageView?